# Oracle: Selecting current and most recent previous value (Appending new columns)

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, pivot, aggregate-functions

I been tried for many hours different alternatives with no success.
I am working with an employee dataset that creates a new row after each data change to conserve history. Also for the same **effective_date**, you can have more than one change by using **effective_sequence** field. An employee data looks like this:

| EMPLOYEE_ID | EFFECTIVE_DATE | EFFECTIVE_SEQ | ADRESS | PHONE | EMAIL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 505 | 01/01/2020 | 1 | MyHome 01 | 1113889 | cparker@mail.com |
| 505 | 15/12/2019 | 2 | My Adress 02 | 1168206 | cparker@mail.com |
| 505 | 15/12/2019 | 1 |  | 1168206 |  |

I need to bring the select * of the current value, appending a select * for the last value. For example:

| EMPLOYEE_ID_NOW | EFFECTIVE_DATE_NOW | EFFECTIVE_SEQ_NOW | ADRESS_NOW | PHONE_NOW | EMAIL_NOW | EMPLOYEE_ID_PREV | EFFECTIVE_DATE_PREV | EFFECTIVE_SEQ_PREV | ADRESS_PREV | PHONE_PREV | EMAIL_PREV |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 505 | 01/01/2020 | 1 | MyHome 01 | 1113889 | cparker@mail.com | 505 | 15/12/2019 | 2 | My Adress 02 | 1168206 | cparker@mail.com |

Version of **Oracle is 11g**

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: `employee_id_now` and `employee_id_prev` doesn't make sense. If the employee id changes, how are you matching the rows by employee?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To recorver the last version of a table containing a historical date you must do two things first

**Identify the Primary of the Entity**

This is the *primary key* of your original data whithout considering the versioning.

I assume this is `EMPLOYEE_ID`

**Identify the Primary Key and Order of the History Table**

In well educated databases all tables have a primary key, so I assume that the columns
`EMPLOYEE_ID    EFFECTIVE_DATE  EFFECTIVE_SEQ` are such primary key or at least are unique.

I'd also assume that the order of the history versions (within one employee) is defined through

`ORDER BY EFFECTIVE_DATE, EFFECTIVE_SEQ`

If this is clarified you get the *last version* using the `ROW_NUMBER` aggregated function as follows

```
with emp as (
select EMPLOYEE_ID, EFFECTIVE_DATE, EFFECTIVE_SEQ, ADRESS,
row_number() over (partition by EMPLOYEE_ID /* partition by the entity PK */
                   order by EFFECTIVE_DATE desc, EFFECTIVE_SEQ desc) as rn /* use DESCendet history order */
from tab)
select * from emp
where rn = 1
```

If you want to add some *previous* columns simple add for each required column a `LAG` function as illustrated below for `ADDRESS`.

> note that this is valid only for the *historized attributes* - it is not valid for the primary key columns. So you can't deduce the previous version of the `EMPLOYEE_ID` as in your sample data.

`lag(ADRESS,1,null)` basically means that you need the *first* previous version and if it doesn't exists provide `null` - so you may vary if you need more history or other default values.

```
with emp as (
select EMPLOYEE_ID, EFFECTIVE_DATE, EFFECTIVE_SEQ, ADRESS,
lag(ADRESS,1,null) over (partition by EMPLOYEE_ID  
                   order by EFFECTIVE_DATE, EFFECTIVE_SEQ) as ADRESS_PREV, 
row_number() over (partition by EMPLOYEE_ID   /* partition by the entity PK */
                   order by EFFECTIVE_DATE desc, EFFECTIVE_SEQ desc) as rn  /* use history order */
from tab)
select * from emp
where rn = 1
```

Sample output

```
EMPLOYEE_ID EFFECTIVE_DATE      EFFECTIVE_SEQ ADRESS       ADRESS_PREV          RN
----------- ------------------- ------------- ------------ ------------ ----------
        505 01.01.2020 00:00:00             1 MyHome 01    My Adress 02          1
        506 15.12.2019 00:00:00             1 Sweet Home                         1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` and conditional aggregation:

```
select employee_id,
    max(effective_date) effective_date_now,
    max(case when rn = 1 then effective_seq end) as effective_seq_now,
    max(case when rn = 1 then address       end) as address_now,
    max(case when rn = 1 then phone         end) as phone_now,
    max(case when rn = 1 then email         end) as email_now,
    min(effective_date) effective_date_prev,
    max(case when rn = 2 then effective_seq end) as effective_seq_prev,
    max(case when rn = 2 then address       end) as address_prev,
    max(case when rn = 2 then phone         end) as phone_prev,
    max(case when rn = 2 then email         end) as email_prev
from (
    select e.*, 
        row_number() over(partition by employee_id order by effective_date desc, effective_seq desc) n
    from emp e
) e
where rn <= 2
group by employee_id
```

Answer (score 0):

As you want entire previous row of the employee, you can use the `CTE`, analytical function `row_number` and `self join` as follows:

```
With cte as 
(Select t.*, 
        row_number() over (partition by employee_id  
                           order by effective_date desc, effecrive_seq desc) as rn
   From your_table t
)
Select t1.*, t2.*
  From cte t1 left join cte t2
    On t1.employee_id = t2.employee_id and t2.rn = 2
 Where t1.rn = 1
```

Comment: Sure simple, love it. thank you very much!